# Mouse back and forward buttons don't work unless I hold another mouse button

Tags: mouse, 17.04, button

So I've been using the event tester the one that is brought up when you type

```
 xev | grep ', button'
```

I've been looking at the way forward and back buttons respond. These are mapped to 8 and 9. However they do not respond unless I am holding another mouse button

```
state 0x400, button 8, same_screen YES
state 0x400, button 9, same_screen YES
```

Interestingly the other buttons display a different output

```
state 0x0, button 1, same_screen YES
state 0x100, button 1, same_screen YES
state 0x0, button 2, same_screen YES
state 0x200, button 2, same_screen YES
state 0x0, button 3, same_screen YES
state 0x400, button 3, same_screen YES
state 0x0, button 4, same_screen YES
state 0x800, button 4, same_screen YES
state 0x0, button 5, same_screen YES
state 0x1000, button 5, same_screen YES
```

Not sure what to do?

Computer info:

```
Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit
Intel® Core™ i3 CPU M 350 @ 2.27GHz × 4 
AMD® Redwood
```

Mouse:

```
Perixx MX-1000
```